With `react-window`, The sticky table header breaks away when scrolling
I am building the table with react-window and react-window-infinite-loader to these requirements.
Requirements

Vertical direction
Infinite scroll
List virtualization
Fixed height of table
The sticky table header

With referring Github issues of react-window, I was able to implement the table like below.
// Page.tsx
import { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  CSSProperties,
  Fragment,
  HTMLProps,
  createContext,
  forwardRef,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { FixedSizeList } from "react-window";
import InfiniteLoader from "react-window-infinite-loader";

import style from "../styles/table.css?url";

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    href: style,
  },
];

type TableContext = {
  top?: number;
  setTop: (top: number) => unknown;
};

type Item = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  createdAt: string;
  age: number;
  hex: string;
};

const Context = createContext<TableContext>({
  top: null!,
  setTop: null!,
});

function TableHead() {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Content</th>
        <th scope="col">Created At</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
        <th scope="col">Hex Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  );
}

export interface TableRowProps {
  item: Item;
  style: CSSProperties;
}

function TableRow(props: TableRowProps) {
  const { item, style } = props;
  return (
    <tr style={{ ...style }}>
      <td height={60}>{item.id}</td>
      <td>{item.title.toUpperCase()}</td>
      <td>{item.content}</td>
      <td>{item.createdAt}</td>
      <td>{item.age}</td>
      <td>{item.hex}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

const TableInnerElement = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>>(
  function TableInnerElement({ children, ...props }, ref) {
    const { top } = useContext(Context);

    return (
      <div {...props} ref={ref}>
        <table style={{ position: "absolute", top, width: "100%" }}>
          <TableHead />
          <tbody>{children}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
);


// Emulate fetching Apis.
function createItems(size: number) {
  const newItems = Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((_, index) => {
    const id = size + index;
    const title = Math.random()
      .toString(16)
      .replace(/(\d|\.)/g, "");
    const content = Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .replace(/(\d|\.)/g, "");
    const createdAt = new Date().toLocaleString();
    const age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20;
    const hexCode = Math.random().toString(16).replace(/\./g, "").slice(0, 6);
    return {
      id,
      title,
      content,
      createdAt,
      age,
      hex: hexCode,
    } satisfies Item;
  });
  return newItems;
}

// Emulate network delay.
function wait(interval: number = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(null!);
    }, interval);
  });
}

export default function Page() {
  const [top, setTop] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    items: [] as Item[],
    isLoading: false,
  });
  const itemCount = state.items ? state.items.length + 1 : 0;
  const listRef = useRef(null as FixedSizeList | null);
  async function fetchNextItems() {
    setState((currentState) => ({
      ...currentState,
      isLoading: true,
    }));
    await wait(3000);
    setState((currentState) => {
      const maxLength = currentState.items.length;
      return {
        items: currentState.items.concat(createItems(maxLength)),
        isLoading: false,
      };
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(() => ({
      isLoading: true,
      items: createItems(0),
    }));
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      isLoading: false,
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          top,
          setTop,
        }}
      >
        <InfiniteLoader
          isItemLoaded={(index) => !!(state && state.items.at(index))}
          itemCount={itemCount}
          loadMoreItems={() => {
            if (!state.isLoading) {
              fetchNextItems();
            }
          }}
        >
          {({ onItemsRendered, ref: loaderRef }) => {
            return (
              <FixedSizeList
                height={600}
                itemCount={itemCount}
                itemSize={60}
                overscanCount={4}
                width={"100%"}
                className="pageTable"
                ref={(ref) => {
                  loaderRef(ref);
                  listRef.current = ref;
                }}
                useIsScrolling
                onItemsRendered={(props) => {
                  // @ts-expect-error Style for rendering items on table.
                  const style = listRef.current?._getItemStyle(
                    // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
                    props.overscanStartIndex
                  );

                  if (style && "top" in style) {
                    const nextTop = style?.top ?? 0;
                    setTop(nextTop as number);
                  }

                  return onItemsRendered(props);
                }}
                innerElementType={TableInnerElement}
              >
                {({ index }) => {
                  const item = state.items?.at(index);
                  if (!item) {
                    return <Fragment key={"fragment"} />;
                  }
                  return <TableRow item={item} style={{}} />;
                }}
              </FixedSizeList>
            );
          }}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      </Context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

/* table.css */
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pageTable {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.pageTable thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}
.pageTable tr > td, .pageTable tr > th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(1), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 72px;
  width: 72px;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(2), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(3), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(3) {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(4), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 180px;
  min-width: 180px;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(5), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.pageTable tr > td:nth-child(6), .pageTable tr > th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 230px;
  min-width: 230px;
}

Everything works fine. But there is one problem yet.
When scrolling upward, table header often detached from the top part of the table.
Here is the captured video.
Example
If I switched sticky to absolute in thead styling, then layouts of th elements in thead, and td elements in tbody do not matches.
Are there any ways to prevent sticky header jumping from table when user are scrolling?
